# Why should we call join after invokeAll method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, invokeall

I am trying to learn about the ForkJoinPool framework and came across the below example:

```
 public class ArrayCounter extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
 int[] array;
 int threshold = 100_000;
 int start;
 int end;

 public ArrayCounter(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    this.array = array;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  protected Integer compute() {
    if (end - start < threshold) {
        return computeDirectly();
    } else {
        int middle = (end + start) / 2;

        ArrayCounter subTask1 = new ArrayCounter(array, start, middle);
        ArrayCounter subTask2 = new ArrayCounter(array, middle, end);

        invokeAll(subTask1, subTask2);


        return subTask1.join() + subTask2.join();
    }
 }

 protected Integer computeDirectly() {
    Integer count = 0;

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
}
```

Main :

```
  public class ForkJoinRecursiveTaskTest
  {
  static final int SIZE = 10_000_000; 
  static int[] array = randomArray();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayCounter mainTask = new ArrayCounter(array, 0, SIZE);
  ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
  Integer evenNumberCount = pool.invoke(mainTask);
  System.out.println("Number of even numbers: " + evenNumberCount);
  }
  static int[] randomArray() {
  int[] array = new int[SIZE];
  Random random = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  array[i] = random.nextInt(100);
  }
  return array;
  }
  }
```

According to the Java Docs,invokeAll() submits the tasks to the pool and returns the results as well.Hence no need for a separate join(). can someone please explain why a separate join is needed in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your example, you are using `RecursiveTask<Integer>`
so you are expecting to return a value from `compute()` method.

let's look at `invokAll(t1,t12)` signature.

`static void invokeAll(ForkJoinTask<?> t1, ForkJoinTask<?> t2)`

so  `invokeAll()` doesn't have  return a value.
according to the documentation :

> Forks the given tasks, returning when isDone holds for each task or an (unchecked) exception is encountered, in which case the exception is rethrown.

**So:**

`return subTask1.join() + subTask2.join();` is the key for your example.
both tasks are merged after each complete the task passing the result recursivly to the next call of `compute()` method.

`task.join()`

> Returns the result of the computation when it is done.

Answer (score 3):

As per javadoc, [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#join())

> Returns the ***result of the computation when it is done***. This method
>   differs from get() in that abnormal completion results in
>   RuntimeException or Error, not ExecutionException, and that interrupts
>   of the calling thread do not cause the method to abruptly return by
>   throwing InterruptedException.

So, when task is done, `join` helps you to get the computed value, which you are adding later together.

```
return subTask1.join() + subTask2.join();
```